# Removing pending orphan activities in Landscape

Tags: 12.04, server, landscape

I am using the hosted Canonical Landscape to manage my Ubuntu servers. Recently, I migrated an Ubuntu 12.04.1 virtual machine from one host to another. After the migration, the server was unable to contact Landscape. Based on the Landscape documentation, I removed the server from Landscape, and re-registered it. It worked beautifully and the server is in contact with the service.

However, while the server was out-of-touch, several "Resynchronize computer" activities were created and were left in a Pending or In Progress status when the server was de-registered. They did not get removed when the server was removed from Landscape.

**How can I remove these orphaned activities?**

I have tried to manually cancel them, but the action buttons are greyed out when the task is opened.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have 1 orphaned activity that's been there since I set up Landscape. I added a computer twice, and the one of the activities is now permanently pending it seems

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend you file an support case about this by clicking on the "SUPPORT" link at the top of the landscape GUI.

If you don't get a response, please reply here and I'll make sure it gets taken care of.

Of the top of my head, it looks like something is very wrong with the client, as a re-synchronization event should not happen under normal circumstances.  Those activities should ***also*** not be stuck there, and thus there is no normal mechanism to delete them (short of deleting the computer and re-adding it).

Comment: Thanks - I have submitted the support case. I will follow up here after a little bit.